# Hibernate Search/Lucene : String field cannot be used for sorting "indexed with multiple values per document, use SORTED_SET instead"

Tags: java, lucene, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I have following model .

```
public class FeatureMeta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String uri;

    @Column
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    @Column
    private String businessDesc;

    @Field
    @Column
    private String logicalDesc;

    .
    .

}
```

I am trying to sort the documents by "name" as follows :

```
org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
                    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(aggrBuilder.build(), FeatureMeta.class);
.
.    

SortFieldContext sortCtx = queryBuilder.sort().byField("name",SortField.Type.STRING);
jpaQuery.setSort(sortCtx.createSort());
.
```

But Lucene throws following exception ?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type mismatch: name was indexed with
>   multiple values per document, use SORTED_SET instead  at
>   org.apache.lucene.uninverting.FieldCacheImpl$SortedDocValuesCache.createValue(FieldCacheImpl.java:678)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.uninverting.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.uninverting.FieldCacheImpl.getTermsIndex(FieldCacheImpl.java:646)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.uninverting.FieldCacheImpl.getTermsIndex(FieldCacheImpl.java:626)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.uninverting.UninvertingReader.getSortedDocValues(UninvertingReader.java:256)
>     at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getSorted(DocValues.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$TermOrdValComparator.getSortedDocValues(FieldComparator.java:762)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$TermOrdValComparator.getLeafComparator(FieldComparator.java:767)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue.getComparators(FieldValueHitQueue.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$SimpleFieldCollector.getLeafCollector(TopFieldCollector.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:812)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:535)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:523)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LazyQueryState.search(LazyQueryState.java:103)

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Actually, before anything else you should check which analyzer you are using on the `name` field. The analyzer probably has a tokenizer, which will result in multi-valued fields, which cannot be sorted on.
Try adding a different field for sorting, and use an analyzer with a `KeywordTokenizer` on this field:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "sort_analyzer",
   tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
   filters = {
       @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
       @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
   }
)
public class FeatureMeta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String uri;

    @Column
    @Field
    @Field(name = "name_sort", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "sort_analyzer"))
    private String name;

    @Field
    @Column
    private String businessDesc;

    @Field
    @Column
    private String logicalDesc;

    .
    .

}
```

Then sort on this new field, instead of the default one:

```
SortFieldContext sortCtx = queryBuilder.sort().byField("name_sort",SortField.Type.STRING);
```

---

Original answer (the points I made are still valid):

Not sure what causes the exception in your case, but try fixing these issues in your code:

1. Add a `@SortableField` annotation on the `name` property
2. Do not use `queryBuilder.sort().byField("name",SortField.Type.STRING)`, just use `queryBuilder.sort().byField("name")`

If it doesn't work, maybe you should try to wipe your indexes and reindex.

Comment: thank you for the answer. However I cannot use Field annotation twice for a field. Eclipse gives the error : "Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type Field. Only annotation types marked Repeatable can be used multiple times at one target."

Comment: i just create a new property in the Model.

Comment: Seems you are using an older version of Hibernate Search; use @Fields({ @Field(...), @Field(...) }) instead